# Python IDE for beginner student

Tags: python, ide

I’m looking for an IDE for python, friendly to beginners. Currently working with java in BlueJ in class but should be moving to eclipse by the end of the year.

I’d love to do some self-study in Python, any recommendations would be very welcome.

Budget would be up to £50

Comment: Please [search the site first](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=python+ide+is%3Aq) before asking yet another Python IDE question

Comment: I did, I found nothing useful. Whilst there are multitudes of ide questions in general, there are none for students or beginners as far as I could see. But if you could please link to where this question was asked before and had answers I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Then at least describe what *friendly to beginners* is....

Comment: My apologies, I didn’t realise it was a language barrier issue. Friendly to beginners means it’s easy for a beginner to work with. So in this usage, the difference between GarageBand and Logic X or as I said in my example, BlueJ and eclipse.

Comment: Did you try PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried many, many, many Python IDEs and nothing comes close to holding a candle to [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Modern, intuitive, powerful, a joy to work with - and the community edition is free, even for commercial use.

I use it daily both at work and at home and can't imagine using any other Python IDE (be sure to learn the debugger - it's your best friend ;-).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt python IDLE or my personal favorite and my recommendation is sublime text. It's amazing, beginner friendly and has a lot of lots of features for python. Plugins are available for python. If you are also looking for light weight then sublime text is a good choice

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyCharm or Sublime Text 3, but speaking from personal experiences, PyCharm is best for pythhon, on using Sublime Text 3, a popup message will irritate you every hour to make purchase of sublime Text License, While in PyCharm you can go for Community Edition which is completely free, you can also use VS Code but its editor not a python IDE

Comment: Welcome on the SoftwareRecs SE! I suggest to use more sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Another favorite of mine is [repl.it](https://repl.it).  It lets you collaborate with other people if you need help with your code and doesn't require you to install anything.  You can also access your code from anywhere, as your code is stored in the cloud.